# Complicated select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to write a select statement that I find very complicated.
My db:

```
Students
(student_id, name, group, year, specialization, scolarship_eval_score)

Scolarships
(scolarship_id, name, company, description, duration)

Applicants
(student_id, scolarship_id)
```

What I need to retrive is:
For all the scolarships with the most applicants find the name of the scolarship, the company, number of applicants and the average of students' scores.

I find this very hard to do. I'm a beginer in sql. So far I have retrieved the number of applicants for each scolarship, now I should find the maximum and for that scolarship return the other required fields.

This is what I have so far

```
select applicants.scolarship_id, count(applicants.scolarship_id)
from applicants
group by applicants.scolarship_id;
```

Can you help me solve that select. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use join. like this

```
select a.*,total from Scolarships a
join(
select applicants.scolarship_id, count(applicants.scolarship_id) as total
from applicants
group by applicants.scolarship_id) b on a.scolarship_id=b.scolarship_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the additional fields, you will need to join on to both the `Scolarships` and `Students` table.

Example join:

`SELECT * 
FROM Applicants a
INNER JOIN Scolarships sc
    ON a.scolarship_id = sc.scolarship_id
INNER JOIN Students st
    ON a.students_id = st.students_id`

Then I will leave it up to you to attempt to select the correct Scolarship. You may also want to look at aggregate functions that will help you compute the average score.

Comment: This only joins the two main tables. I need to find the course with the maximum number of applicants and for that course retrieve other results.

Comment: @GeR I am not suggesting this is the answer, but am guiding you in the right direction. Try combining it with the group by in your question, an order on the count and the LIMIT keyword.